# Submenu get hidden after adding scrollbar to dropdwon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Full code available here https://www.codeply.com/p/eMoXymAE4E

There is a long menu dropdown and i want to add scroll bar which i added using

```
max-height:200px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Which result in hiding sub menu item inside scrollbar
[image]

If i add

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Then horizontal scrollbar get hidden and i can't get view of submenu items.
[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code (create a snippet).

Comment: you can see code here
https://www.codeply.com/p/eMoXymAE4E

Comment: set `position: absolute` to the `sub-dropdown`

Comment: @KunalTanwar it's already absolute

Comment: Somehow they manage to get it working here: [Scrollable menu with pop out submenus](https://codepen.io/agop/pen/VwwMGR)